# Removed products from a category but still showing

Tags: category, category-products, reindex, category-tree, category-view

1. I removed a bunch of products from a category and it's still showing in the webshop.

[image]
[image]

What I've done is:

- Reindexed all indexes
- Cleared all caches

  2. Another problem that keeps happening is that I can not sort this category and few of the subcategories as well.

Does anyone know how to solve both of these problems? I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: can you try to do re indexing from admin ?